# Wordpress WooCommerce admin-custom-order-fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I install [admin-custom-order-fields](http://www.woothemes.com/products/admin-custom-order-fields/) after enabling, I add 3 fields from admin area.
But they are not showing on frontend checkout page.

I read the documentation, and set the attributes as it suggest.but no luck.
Can you please guide me to the right path.

I'm using http://cardinal.swiftideas.com/documentation/changelog/?TB_iframe=true&width=1024&height=800 if this make any change.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by disableing very other plugins and clear any caches you have.
Second you can check the debug.log file from wp-content.

Tell me if you still have this proablem.